# Off-canvas menu from bottom of page (Foundation 6)

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to make an off-canvas menu in foundation. I want it to come up from the bottom of the page, as opposed to right or left. I just want the menu to be horizontal instead of vertical, and to come in from the bottom, instead of coming in from the sides. Does anyone that knows Foundation 6 know how to do this? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Foundation does not do this automatically. If you want the menu at the bottom of the screen, a good non-flexbox way to do that is to set it absolute or sticky with bottom: 0; However, because of the way that off canvas works, it is the full height of the page that it is wrapped in, with content starting at the top.

Most likely you might want to consider how important it is to push the existing content over, in the ZURB Foundation off-canvas way. If that is not critical, you can likely duplicate this behavior much easier by using the reveal / modal pattern and customizing it.

There is a trend right now towards full screen mobile navigation that looks like a dark colored modal that is full screen. You might consider it as an option.